# contribution to main menu

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

How to determine which plugins are contributing to the main menu?

Probably there is a problem with a project configuration and sometimes new elements are added to the main menu when I add plugins to the run configuration.

Comment: @MozenRath Probbaly about developmnet of Eclipse plugins...

Comment: now that you have mentioned eclipse, i think it is about finding which plugins are trouble-making for a general eclipse user.

Comment: @MozenRath, yes, this question is about eclipse platform. I don't know why but sometimes in main menu new elements appear. They come from nowhere. I do no explicit actions for them to appear. And that is why I would like to find out their host plugin to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Plug-In Spy to see which Plug-In is contributing to the menus..see for an explanation http://scratsh.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/eclipse-3-5-plug-in-spy-and-menus/

Comment: The plug-in spy cannot be used for this particular case as it does _not_ return which plug-in that contributed a specific menu or toolbar item. AFAIK, there are no way to find this information - except for searching through the sources!

Comment: No not directly, but in 99% the Id of the item gives you an idea of the contributing bundle, e.g. jdt would not contribute a menu with id org.eclipse.buckminster.[...]

Comment: Agree, but there are absolutely no guarantees :-) I know this from hard experience... it took me several hours to figure out that from Eclipse 3.2 and forward you can even specify your own id for markers, applications and other artifacts, where the ID was traditionally constructed... You always have been for commands.